# How to truncate a string after a specific word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, truncate

I have a string of datatype `nvarchar(max)` like this:

```
declare @cbCheckdate nvarchar(max) ='
{"request_id":"364202","final_decision":"FAIL","derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
"derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
"derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
"derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0","derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0",
"cbResponseMsg":"Final Decision:FAIL || Number of active MFI :1 || Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0 
|| Number of Total Active Institutions :2 || FAILOve'
```

I need to truncate the above string like below :

```
declare @cbCheckdate nvarchar(max) ='{"request_id":"364202","final_decision":"FAIL","derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
"derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
"derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
"derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0","derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0"'
```

Basically what I need to do is: if my string contains this word `cbResponseMsg` then I need to remove this words and all the text after it.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL version 2014

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on SQL Server **2014** and don't have the built-in JSON support yet, I would probably write a small function for this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TruncateAfter(@Input NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @DelimiterPos INT;
    SET  @DelimiterPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Input);

    IF (@DelimiterPos > 0)
        SET @Result = TRIM(LEFT(@Input, @DelimiterPos - 1));
    ELSE
        SET @Result = @Input;

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

Now, you can call this function with two parameters - your input, and the "delimiter" you're looking for. If the delimiter is found, any text from its position on is truncated - if the delimiter doesn't appear in the input, the whole input is returned:

```
DECLARE @cbCheckdate NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{"request_id":"364202","final_decision":"FAIL","derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
"derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
"derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
"derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0","derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0",
"cbResponseMsg":"Final Decision:FAIL || Number of active MFI :1 || Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0 
|| Number of Total Active Institutions :2 || FAILOve'

DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'cbResponseMsg';

SELECT 
    dbo.TruncateAfter (@cbCheckdate, @Delimiter)
```

should return the desired output.

Comment: I wouldn't harry to do that in a user defined scalar function. They are notorious for performance issues.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: to my knowledge, as long as you don't "hide" any actual data access (using a `SELECT`) inside your scalar function, performance shouldn't really be much of an issue. This stored function is only operating on the input parameters and doesn't do any "heavy lifting" that way - so I'm pretty sure it should be quite okay

Answer (score 0):

This input is probably in JSON format, so if you use SQL Server 2016+, you may use `JSON_MODIFY()` function to delete the `cbResponseMsg` key from the input JSON:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @cbCheckdate nvarchar(max) = '{
   "request_id":"364202",
   "final_decision":"FAIL",
   "derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
   "derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
   "derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
   "derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0",
   "derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0",
   "cbResponseMsg":"Final Decision:FAIL || Number of active MFI :1 || Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0 || Number of Total Active Institutions :2 || FAILOve"
}'

SELECT @cbCheckdate = JSON_MODIFY(@cbCheckdate, '$.cbResponseMsg', NULL)
SELECT @cbCheckdate
```

Result:

```
{
   "request_id":"364202",
   "final_decision":"FAIL",
   "derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
   "derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
   "derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
   "derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0",
   "derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0"
}
```

Comment: 'JSON_MODIFY' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Mar1009 Yes, I mentioned this in the answer, JSON support was introduced in SQL Server 2016. If your text is valid JSON, you may need to search for UDF to parse this JSON or try to use another approach, probably based on string or XML transformations.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
set @cbCheckdate = left(@cbCheckdate, CHARINDEX('cbResponseMsg', @cbCheckdate) -2)  select @cbCheckdate
```

Comment: This approach does ***NOT WORK*** if the `@cbCheckdate` string doesn't contain `cbResponseMsg` - in that case, you get: 
`Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 3  
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a safe way to do that, without user defined functions, using the built in functions `stuff`, `charindex`, `reverse`, `len` and `sign`:

```
declare @cbCheckdate nvarchar(max) ='
{"request_id":"364202","final_decision":"FAIL","derived_Attribute_1":"PASS|Number of active MFI :1",
"derived_Attribute_4":"PASS|Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0",
"derived_Attribute_3":"PASS|Number of Total Active Institutions :2",
"derived_Attribute_2":"FAIL|Overdue Amount:17984.0","derived_Attribute_5":"PASS|Write off amount:0.0",
"cbResponseMsg":"Final Decision:FAIL || Number of active MFI :1 || Total Exposure + Applied Amount :53051.0 
|| Number of Total Active Institutions :2 || FAILOve';

declare @delimiter nvarchar(100) = '"cbResponseMsg"';

SELECT  REVERSE(
            STUFF(
                REVERSE(@cbCheckdate), 
                1,
                CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@delimiter), REVERSE(@cbCheckdate)) + 
                    LEN(@delimiter) * SIGN(CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @cbCheckdate)),
            '')
        )
```

Here's the breakdown, from the inside out:

- `CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @cbCheckdate)` will return 0 if the delimiter is not found, or a positive integer if it is found in the string.
- `SIGN` will return `0` for `0`, `1` for a positive number or (irrelevant to this case) `-1` for a negative number.
- `CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@delimiter), REVERSE(@cbCheckdate)) + 
   LEN(@delimiter) * SIGN(CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @cbCheckdate))` will return `0` is the delimiter is not found, or a positive integer representing the number of chars between the beginning of the delimiter to the end of the string.
- The `STUFF` function put in an empty string into the source string, starting at the first char (`1`) and replacing the number of chars it takes in as the third argument.
- And finally, since this is all being done on the reversed string, `reverse` the result one more time to return the string in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
SELECT
        CASE
         WHEN @cbCheckdate LIKE '%cbResponseMsg%' THEN LEFT(@cbCheckdate, CHARINDEX('cbResponseMsg', @cbCheckdate)-3)
         ELSE @cbCheckdate
        END
```

Comment: **Note:** [A case expression does not always short-circuit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12941/68798), which means that under some circumstances, this code might throw an error for the `left` function.

Comment: Isn't it the behavior for integers? Never had issues when using it for (var)char

Comment: I don't think the data type is the problem... I just know it's not guaranteed to short-circuit, Don't know the exact conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a simple, effective query:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(@cbCheckdate, CHARINDEX('cbResponseMsg', @cbCheckdate)-3)
WHERE 
    @cbCheckdate LIKE '%cbResponseMsg%'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    @cbCheckdate
WHERE 
    @cbCheckdate NOT LIKE '%cbResponseMsg%'
```